# Google Places API AutoComplete error Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I followed google tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android) to implement an autocomplete searching in Android. once I constructed the app and run it I get this error

```
 returned from sslSelect() with result 0, error code 2
 returned from sslSelect() with result 1, error code 2
```

any clue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was solved for me when I exchanged the API key. I was using the one under Android device, I changed it to the one "Key for browser apps (with referers)" and it worked for me although I'm using Android device.